# React Native SectionList/ListView view desc sort order not maintained

Tags: javascript, sorting, listview, reactjs, react-native

I guess this is more like understanding of javascript sorting or how sections are rendered in SectionList or ListView. I have a data source where I need to display the results in desc order of ageGroup. My row object has like:

```
[{name: 'Saurabh', ageGroup:'1'}, {name: 'John', ageGroup:'0'}]
```

When I sort it desc order by ageGroup I can see the sorting correctly but when I pass this sorted array to section headers sort order is lost. However, this works perfectly if I change ageGroup to characters instead of numbers say replacing 0 by A and 1 by B.
Here is my code so far - earlier I tried ListView with sectionHeaders, later changed it to SectionList but it is not working either way. How can I render my list elements in descending order of ageGroup?

Here is my code :

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  SectionList
} from 'react-native';

import _ from 'lodash';

let dataSource = [{
    name: 'Saurabh',
    ageGroup: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    ageGroup: '0'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    ageGroup: '1'
  },
]

// let dataSource = [{
//     name: 'Saurabh',
//     ageGroup: 'B'
//   },
//   {
//     name: 'John',
//     ageGroup: 'A'
//   },
//   {
//     name: 'Alex',
//     ageGroup: 'B'
//   },
// ]


dataSource = _.orderBy(dataSource, ['ageGroup'], ['desc']);
// dataSource = dataSource.sort((a,b) => b-a);

console.log('dataSource: ' + JSON.stringify(dataSource));

dataSource = _.groupBy(dataSource, d => d.ageGroup);
dataSource = _.reduce(dataSource, (acc, next, index) => {
  acc.push({
    key: index,
    data: next
  })
  return acc
}, []);
console.log('dataSource: ' + JSON.stringify(dataSource));

export default class SectionListExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    this.renderSectionHeader = this.renderSectionHeader.bind(this);
  }


  renderItem(item) {
    return ( <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 14,
          color: 'blue'
        }
      } > {
        item.item.name
      } < /Text>
    );
  }


  renderSectionHeader(headerItem) {
    return ( <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: '700',
          color: 'gray'
        }
      } > {
        headerItem.section.key
      } < /Text>
    );
  }


  render() {

    return ( <
      SectionList renderItem = {
        this.renderItem
      }
      renderSectionHeader = {
        this.renderSectionHeader
      }
      sections = {
        dataSource
      }
      keyExtractor = {
        (item) => item.name
      }
      removeClippedSubviews = {
        false
      }
      style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          marginTop: 100
        }
      }
      />
    );
  }
}
```